# Dell Inspiron Intel 7260 Wifi connects and then drops on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, dell

I've been trying to connect my wireless card unsuccessfully. I've tried similar questions/answers with no luck. I tried with Ubuntu 13.10 with same results but loading latest *iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode* did work for a while, till now with 14.04.

The laptop's wifi card is "Intel Corporation Wireless 7260".

**dmesg | grep iwlwifi**

```
[   31.566955] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 63 for MSI/MSI-X
[   31.865873] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   31.887194] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[   31.887249] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
```

**sudo  lshw -C Network**

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 73
       serial: fc:f8:ae:af:ad:34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:63 memory:b0500000-b0501fff
```

**iwconfig**

```
      wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
```

Tried using   *iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode*  and   *iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode* but same results.

Comment: Here are three or four more just like it. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217691 Please see post #21.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I read the 3 page post but yet they can't get to solve this. I'll keep looking.

Comment: See my bug report and add some more heat by adding yourself as affected: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1305305

Answer (score 1):

I'm newbee in linux, so in my case a solution is like a "terrible crutch", but it works for me now. I use the same linux - Kubuntu 14.04 and chip Intel-7260 rev.73.

I found out, that system on my notebook uses wlwifi-7260-7.ucode. Also, I have tried to make *something* from backports. No, realy, I don't know, what exactly I have made %(

Eventually I just substituted the file! Instead "**wlwifi-7260-7.ucode**" I copied with same name file **wlwifi-7260-8.ucode** and voila- it's works fairly well:)

Yeah, I know, that is stupid. I just haven't any more time to digging.

Comment: Thank you Vijit. I'm using your suggestion, but still I have continuous disconections. Only this time it do not ask me for the Wifi password each time it reconects.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my brand new laptop on Ubuntu 14.04 and the intel wireless card. At the end, the solution was in my router configuration: I disabled `the Super G Mode` in my router and it worked. The connection is now stable and fast.

So, check your router configuration and see if this Super G mode is on, and try to disable it.

Comment: Finally had access to the router but no success, I found nothing like "Super G", thank you anyway jeudyx.