# Ubuntu 14.04: Wireless crash

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dell, crash

I am currently trying to run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 7720 stock model, I was attempting to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS w/ Windows 8.1 SP0. After some issues I was having with grub and windows boot manager conflicting I had to backup my files from my data partition and wipe my drive.

Now, I have just Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed, before I state my issue I would like to note that every time I have attempted to install Ubuntu (10.04, 12.04 and 13.10) on my Laptop, I have had this issue. When I attempt to connect to my wireless Internet, I get a crash of my router (Meaning my whole Internet goes down, WiFi and wired). However when I plug my laptop into a wired connection, it works perfectly fine. Any thoughts?

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 7720 Stock Model
Router: Thomson (Don't know the version ATM)
Modem: Thomson (Don't know the version ATM)

I do have an all in one router/modem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by upgrading the wireless card driver

See this link

[Dell Inspiron Intel 7260 Wifi connects and then drops on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453222/dell-inspiron-intel-7260-wifi-connects-and-then-drops-on-ubuntu-14-04)

and this...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217691